# Turkey e-Visa if I have a ticket for an onward journey (as opposed to a return ticket)

Tags: tourist-visas, turkey

I'm flying to the US somewhere in the middle of August 2019, and I would like to spend a few days in Istanbul on the way/way back. As such, the website for the e-Visa application asks for proof of a return ticket. I will only have proof of an onward ticket for this. Can I still obtain an e-Visa somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about a visa for the US or for Turkey here? I presume you are talking about going to Turkey on the way or way back from the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly alright. All you need is a confirmed ticket out of the country. It doesn’t have to go back to the origin.

*Onward* in this case is as good as *Return*. I have done this a number of times, and have never had a problem.

Think about this: If an eVisa disallowed a transit visit to the country, Turkish airlines would  have lost a ton of its customers who avail free transit stopovers in Istanbul thanks to eVisa.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! A follow up question is also that it asks for proof of a hotel reservation. I'm going to be staying with a friend, so will this be a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. Normally they don't ask about such confirmations when you're there. But if they do, I don't really know whether they will accept staying with a friend just as good as a hotel. I wouldn't think otherwise though.